# Connecting two parallel join models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say that I have Projects, Users, and two ways to connect Users to Projects - Rsvps and Memberships. Like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :projects, :through => :memberships
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships, :class_name => 'User'
end

class Rsvp < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Rsvps and Memberships are different enough in their other functions that I don't especially want to combine them into one model, but I do want to be able to associate Rsvps and Memberships. My ideal-world scenario would be something like this:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :rsvp, :through => [:project, :user]
end
```

but obviously that's a pipe dream.

The two potential solutions I've thought of so far are trying to fake an association with something like

```
def rsvp
  project.rsvps.find(:conditions => {:user_id => user_id})
end
```

but that's less than ideal as it doesn't duplicate all the fun other features that come with Association objects. Alternatively I could add a `membership_id` field to Rsvp, but that smells like it'll attract syncing-related bugs.

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the :conditions parameter to specify the has_one or has_many relationship:

```
has_one ... :conditions => lambda{ ['project_id = ? AND user_id = ?', self.project_id, self.user_id] }
```

I think you can also do this in a shorthand format, but make sure that you use single quotes and not double quotes in your definition:

```
has_one ... :conditions => 'project_id = #{project_id} AND user_id = #{user_id}'
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is substantially different from the second non-solution I proposed - both would generate an Rsvp object rather than an Association object.

Comment: I have modified my post to make it more clear that this actually creates an association.  I was suggesting you use the :conditions on the association declaration rather than in a find function.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. That almost works, but two niggly bits - one, it needs to be something like `:through => :project, :conditions => 'user_id = #{user_id}'` (or else it also looks for the nonexistent membership_id) and two, I needed to *also* specify that the has_one source was :rsvps rather than :rsvp. So ultimately, the association was created with: `has_one :rsvp, :through => :project, :conditions => 'user_id = #{user_id}', :source => :rsvps`. Once I worked that out, it worked perfectly.